# SQL query to resolve overlaps based on priority

Tags: sql, db2

I am looking at writing a query to resolve overlapping date periods based on a column which stores the priority of that row. That helps me to decide if I need to keep that row or replace it with the other overlapping row. For e.g:

```
FromDate   ToDate    Priority
-----------------------------
1/1/2014   6/30/2014     1    --row1
2/1/2014   7/30/2014     2    --row2
```

My results should look like the below

```
FromDate   ToDate     Priority
------------------------------
1/1/2014   6/30/2014     1    --row 1
7/1/2014   7/30/2012     2    --row 2
```

Comment: 2012 is a typo... right?

Comment: What is your RDBMS? If sql server 2012+ have you tried `LAG`?

Comment: [xkcd PSA ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: Yeah. 2012 is a typo. It should be 2014. I am using DB2.

Answer (score 0):

```
with temp1 (FromDate,todate, dt, priority) as                     
(                                                                 
  SELECT FromDate,todate,fromdate as dt  ,Priority                
  FROM mytable                                                    
    UNION ALL                                                     

  SELECT FromDate,todate ,                                        
dt + 1 day as dt  ,Priority                                       
  FROM temp1                                                      
  WHERE dt < todate                                               
)                                                                 
SELECT min(dt) as fromdate, max(dt) as todate, priority           
FROM temp1 a                                                      
where priority = (select min(priority) from temp1 where dt =a.dt) 
group by priority
```